# Saving listbox's file not just its name

Tags: vb.net

Im working on my first injector in VB.NET.
Im trying to save the loaded dll in listbox, but it only saves the name.
I select the dll, inject, it saves my.settings, but once I reopen the injector it only saves the dll's name, not its path, so I have to browse and select it again

I was thinking about maybe I have to save openfiledialog or something but really got no clue

Inject button:

```
My.Settings.dll = New Specialized.StringCollection
My.Settings.dll.AddRange(dll.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray)
My.Settings.Save()

My.Settings.process = SteamTextBox2.Text
My.Settings.Save()
```

On form load:

```
If My.Settings.dll IsNot Nothing Then dll.Items.AddRange(My.Settings.dll.Cast(Of String).ToArray)
```

The problem with this the injector only needs the dll's name without path

```
Dim ExeName As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath)

Private Sub Inject()
  pszLibFileRemote = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
End Sub

OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "DLL (*.dll) |*.dll"
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
OpenFileDialog1.ToString()
If IO.File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
  Dim TargetProcess As Process() = Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(SteamTextBox2.Text)
  If TargetProcess.Length = 0 Then
    ...
  Else
    Call Inject()
```

I want it to load the actual selected file not just it's name

Comment: what do you mean? umm, its a cheat, c++ x86 dll

Comment: I had deleted my comment because I realized `dll` is probably your ListBox

Comment: maybe you can understand it better like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4usoBuFlrfc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help. According to your question, only the filename is loading into your listbox but you want the full path. It appears you have some more going on so you should edit your question to include all the details (nobody wants to watch the youtube video) to make it clearer to us...

Comment: `OpenFileDialog1.ToString()`???  That doesn't do anything.

Comment: yeah, my bad, removed it

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is functionally wrong with your code. I guess the problem is with how you load the paths into the listbox in the first place. Here is some code to do that.

Add a new button called `LoadButton`, then this code for the handler

```
Private Sub LoadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click
    Dim filenames As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Using dialog As New OpenFileDialog
        dialog.Filter = "Application extensions (*.dll)|*.dll|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        dialog.Multiselect = True
        Select Case dialog.ShowDialog()
            Case DialogResult.OK
                filenames = dialog.FileNames
            Case Else
                filenames = Nothing
        End Select
    End Using
    filenames = filenames.Select(Function(fn) System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fn))
    If filenames?.Any() Then dll.Items.AddRange(filenames.ToArray())
End Sub
```

This will put the full path into the listbox. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: The problem with this the injector only needs the dll's name without path
`code`

Comment: Then just select the filename only from the path? `filenames = filenames.Select(Function(fn) System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fn))` (i added it to the answer)

Comment: no, something doesnt seems to work
       `OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "DLL (*.dll) |*.dll"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        OpenFileDialog1.ToString()`
Thats the original load button which one is working. btw Ive edited the thread with a few more codes (which are related to openfiledialog) but I couldnt format it good